# OllyDBG not working properly

Tags: windows, vb6, ollydbg

I'm having problems with **OLLYDBG** in **Win8.1**.

For example, I'm using a simple **VB 6.0** program with a textbox and a command box. When I run it through OLLYDBG in *WinXP*, it shows all referenced text strings properly, while in *Win 8.1* it shows only internal info and random values.

SSE and IP are off.

What I mean is that it doesn't properly read any program in *Win8*, running as admin and attached.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking why a 20c program doesn't work?

You can also start in a debugger.

windbg or ntsd (ntsd is a console program and maybe installed). Both are also from Debugging Tools For Windows.

Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363
```

Install the Windows SDK but just choose the debugging tools.

Create a folder called Symbols in C:\

Start Windbg. File menu - Symbol File Path and enter

```
 srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

then

```
  windbg -o -g -G c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k batfile.bat
```

You can press `F12` to stop it and `kb` will show the call stack (`g` continues the program). If there's errors it will also stop and show them.

Type `lm` to list loaded modules, `x *!*` to list the symbols and `bp <symbolname>` to set a breakpoint

If programming in VB6 then this environmental variable `link=/pdb:none` stores the symbols in the dll rather than seperate files. Make sure you compile the program with No Optimisations and tick the box for Create Symbolic Debug Info. Both on the Compile tab in the Project's Properties.

Also CoClassSyms (microsoft.com/msj/0399/hood/hood0399.aspx) can make symbols from type libraries.

### .